# Not equal to number does not include null SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query in SQL Server for context.

```
SELECT 
    O.OrderID, SUM(P.Quantity) AS SprayGlueCans
FROM 
    FCMDB.dbo.FcoOrders O
JOIN 
    FCMDB.dbo.FcoStyleGroups SG ON SG.OrderID = O.OrderID
JOIN 
    FCMDB.dbo.FcoProducts P ON P.StyleGroupID = SG.StyleGroupID
WHERE
    P.CatalogProductID = 12715 
    AND O.Shipped = 1 
    AND MONTH(O.ShipDate) = 8 
    AND YEAR(O.ShipDate) = 2023 
    AND O.InstallerID <> 3 
    AND InstallerID <> 29
GROUP BY 
    O.OrderID
```

When I run it everything works great except for the fact that the `InstallerID` can be NULL. I expected this to not matter because. I was under the assumption that since NULL is not 3 or 29 then it would be included in the results. But this query seems to leave out everything with a NULL `InstallerID`. I was wondering why this is so.

Is this just how it works? If so am I supposed to be careful to not write queries that have this mistake again? And if that is true are there practices or design choices to best handle or avoid this situation?

Comment: *"I was under the assumption that since NULL is not 3 or 29 then it would be included in the results."* That is not how `NULL` works. `NULL` is an *unknown* value; it is neither equal nor *not* equal to anything. To compare to a `NULL` value you need to use `IS (NOT) NULL`. Alternatively, if you're on 2022 or Azure, you can use `IS DISTINCT FROM` when comparing to *scalar* values: `YourColumn IS DISTINCT FROM 3` will return rows where `YourColumn` does not have the value `3` *including* `NULL` values.

Comment: On a separate note, don't use syntax like `YEAR(O.ShipDate) = 2023` in your `WHERE`; this is *not* SARGable. Use explicit date ranges, such as `YourDate >= '20210101' AND YourDate < '20220101'`.

Comment: A comparison with a NULL returns UNKNOWN, which is neither true nor false. I think you want `((O.InstallerID <> 3 AND O.InstallerID <> 29) OR O.InstallerID IS NULL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, `NULL` values don't work with equality operators. `SomeColumn != 3` will return *UNKNOWN* when `SomeColumn` has a value of `3`, which importantly *isn't* *TRUE*, so the row is omitted from the result set.

When comparing to `NULL`s you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS DISTINCT FROM` (the latter is only supported in Azure or on SQL Server 2022+). For example `(SomeColumn != 3 OR SomeColumn IS NULL)` and `SomeColumn IS DISTINCT FROM 3`.

For your query, this results in the following ((un)comment the solution appropriate for you):

```sql
USE FCMDB; --Connect to the correct DB, there's no need for 3 part naming here
GO

SELECT O.OrderID,
       SUM(P.Quantity) AS SprayGlueCans
FROM dbo.FcoOrders O
    JOIN dbo.FcoStyleGroups SG ON SG.OrderID = O.OrderID
    JOIN dbo.FcoProducts P ON P.StyleGroupID = SG.StyleGroupID
WHERE P.CatalogProductID = 12715
  AND O.Shipped = 1
  AND O.ShipDate >= '20230801'
  AND O.ShipDate < '20230901'
  AND (O.InstallerID NOT IN (3,29) OR O.InstallerID IS NULL)
  --AND O.InstallerID IS DISTINCT FROM 3 AND O.InstallerID IS DISTINCT FROM 29
GROUP BY O.OrderID;
```

You'll notice I switch to a `NOT IN` when using `IS NULL` and I also change your clauses against `ShipDate` to be SARGable. Again, as mentioned in the comments, don't uses clauses like `YEAR(O.ShipDate) = 2023` in the `WHERE`, as indexes can't be used for such queries, which will result in poor(er) performance.

Comment: Thanks I did not know about the SARGable thing it is good to know.

Comment: Very good explained. Another way beside `OR` would be `COALESCE` (but might be slower, I'm not sure).

Comment: It (likely) would be, @JonasMetzler , as that would also make the query non-SARGable.